# copy html block with tags script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have such html code:

```html
<div> 
    <div id="text">text></div>
    <script>$("#text").val('some value');</script>
</div>
```

I copy this html through `.clone()` and edit html inside. Result:

```html
<div> 
    <div id="1-text">text></div>
    <script>$("#text").val('some value');</script>
</div>
```

I want to change id inside tags script. `$("#1-text").val('other value');`
How can I do it?

Comment: I think there should be a better solution that cloning script elements. And divs do not have values.

Comment: I would suggest not doing this. As it'll be very difficult to edit the JS in the script element.

Comment: I need copy html, and I need handler for it, how can I do it in another way?
I don't know exact amount block, so I can't write all handlers at once

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a variable to the outside that dynamically tells you what to select. so if you were to iterate through your values using a loop you can do something like this:

```
$("#text_"+i).val('other value');
```

You could also set a counter and as new divs are added the i increments. So it is flexible.

I'm not exactly sure what your end goal is but I wouldn't recommend this methodology if you're attempting to manipulate the javascript in the `<script>` tag. As I believe that would be cumbersome.

Comment: It's good way, but I seek flexible solution. There are many other functions inside script, such as datepicker and phone masks. If I copy html block, I want to get all functionality of previous block.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy entire html block, you should bind your inline javascript code to this block as a container. Not id. So when you move or copy the block your script will be able to find any elements related to container.

```
<div id="containerOne" class="js-container">
    <div class="js-text" data-text="some value">some value</div>
    <script>
        var $el = $("script").last().closest(".js-container").find(".js-text");
        $el.text($el.data("text"));
    </script>
</div>
```

Hereby you obtain access to elements by class not id. Note using **"js-"** prefix is just for javascript manipulation not for css styling.

Also you don't need to change script itself. You can change values via **"data-"** attributes.

In your external script you can encapsulate any clone logic by various methods. For example:

```
var myModule = {
  clone: function(containerSelector) {
    var $donorEl = $(containerSelector);
    var $donorScript = $donorEl.find('script');
    $script = $("<script />");
    $script.text($donorScript.text());
    $recipientEl = $donorEl.clone();
    $recipientEl.attr('id', 'containerTwo');
    var newValue = 'other value';
    $('.js-text', $recipientEl).data('text', newValue);
    $('body').append($recipientEl);
    $('script', $recipientEl).replaceWith($script);
  }
};

myModule.clone('#containerOne');
```

You can see [the working example](https://jsfiddle.net/yrLkho9k/).